# Sending file over OBEX push profile

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, file-transfer, obex

I've been able to open a raw bluetooth socket to the obex push profile channel of a device. My goal is to be able to send files over the protocol.

Where can I find any info how the headers should be set up and how the communication should work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBEX is specified by the IrDA.  Unfortunately they've started to charge for access to the specification documents, http://www.irda.org/displaycommon.cfm?an=1&subarticlenbr=7#OBEX  However there are copies of the previous version OBEX13.pdf lying around on various places on the internet...

What's your platform BTW.  On .NET (including Compact Framework) there is OBEX support in the 32feet.NET library and full and complete support in the Brecham.Obex library.

http://32feet.codeplex.com/, and Brecham.Obex http://inthehand.com/files/folders/objectexchange/entry6351.aspx

Comment: I will look around, thanks.
My platform is Android <=1.6. Since it has no bluetooth support I'm using this 3d party library: http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/ which just allows one to get a "BluetoothSocket" to a remote device. From there you're unfortunetely on your own.